# Implementing User-ID With Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have added Google Tag Manager to our site, and using the data layer inserted several custom dimensions, including 'user_id'
[Data Layer with user_id shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0cut.png)

The Google Analytics variable in Tag Manager is configured to pass these data layer variables into the coresponding dimensions:
[Tag Manager Variable & Dimensions in Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkYlh.png)

I know this is working as I am able to add this as a secondary dimension in Analytics when viewing reports:
[Analytics with Dimension Shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpUc4.png)

However, the user view that is created when I have set up the User-Id isnt showing anything:
[Creating the User View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4mRH.png)

We installed Tag Manager using the recommended steps:
[Installation of Tag Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkaBD.png)

Do we also need to add the 'Global Site Tag Tracking Code'?
[How to Implement the User-ID in your tracking code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rErJ.png)

If not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually REALLY close. You actually don't need to create the custom dimension.

The correct way is to set the `userId` field in your GA tag (I did it through a GA variable so it is applied everywhere).

[image]

Comment: Hi XTOTHEL, many thanks for your prompt reply. Whilst it's not updated in Analytics yet (I guess there is a bit of a lag?) this is what i'm now getting in the debugger:
      {fieldName: 'userId', value: 13436},

Which i'm guessing is what we are after?

Comment: It's working beautifully - thank you so much for your advice ️

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is exactly correct (what @XTOTHEL answered above), but for those who are reading this, I found these two blog posts helpful (esp if you are using GTM):

- GA UA: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-analytics-user-id-with-google-tag-manager/
- GA4: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-analytics-4-user-id/

And of course, the GA docs: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/4565987?hl=en